# Splitting a dataframe by passing a list of indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df, containing only one column 'Info', which I want to split into multiple dataframes based on a list of indices, ls = [23,76,90,460,790]. If I want to use np.array_split(), how do I pass the list so that it parses the data from these indices with each index being the first row of split dataframes.

Comment: Would using `ls = [23,76,90,460,790]` result in 5 DF's - could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: Yes, first dataframe should start from row 23 to 75, then second one from 76 to 89 and so on.

Comment: and 790 should be "until end"?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53395439/6361531

Comment: @Scott ahh... I didn't find that in my search for a possible duplicate (and thoughtful of you to not immediately close as a duplicate as it leads to your own answer :) - feel free to close as a duplicate (although I prefer my use of zip_longest - but I can add to there or you're more than welcome to add it to your answer there).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can use `np.array_split()` here (you can access the underlying `.values` of the primary DF but you'd get back numpy arrays - not DFs...) - what you can do is use `.iloc` and "slice" from your DF, eg:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

dfs = [df.iloc[s: e] for s, e in zip_longest(ls[::2], ls[1::2])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I think it should work.